# How do I set the value of an inverse relationship in a mapping model?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, core-data-migration, mapping-model

In v1 of my model I have a one to many relationship between a `presentation` and `slides`:

```
presentation---->>slides
```

In v2 I fix this foolishness by adding an inverse one to one:

```
presentation<--->>slides
```

In both models a `slide` belongs to 1 and only 1 `presentation` (although this is not codified within the models).

How do I specify the value expression in the mapping model to create the `slide-->presentation` relationship without creating an `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell it is not possible to do this with a Value Expression in the mapping. The solution is to create a `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclass for the mapping.

In the `NSEntityMigrationPolicy` subclass override `createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:entityMapping:manager:error:`. In this method fetch the related object with a standard `NSFetchRequest` executed in the managers `destinationContext`. Be sure to call `super` to ensure that any other relationships are also migrated.